# Controversial topics over veg vs non veg and ceremonial sacrifices of animals

Tags: scripture, puranas, worship

Does it state outright & clearly anywhere in Hindu scriptures & holy books to NOT eat non veg food? Also, is it true that old rishi munis made sacrificial ceremonies of goat, cows and buffalo during Puja? 
Please support your explanation with specific reference from scriptures or holy books.

Thanks a lot!
Aney D. Patel

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE!  The animal sacrifice part of your question is a duplicate of the linked question, and the vegetarianism portion is probably a duplicate of several questions, so I'm closing your question for the time being.  If you want to revise your question so it's no longer duplicative, then edit it and flag me to undelete it.